# Filter database date in C#

Tags: c#, sql-server

In my database the date and time appear together with the data that was placed, but if I filter by date in C# as it has the time together I can't filter by date. Do I have to create a field for the date and another for the time?

[image]

Comment: Hi, please share a question with a reproducible junk of code. What have you tried since now to solve your problem?

Comment: Please show your data query. For the info given in the question, it should work fine (generally). You seem to have a column for date/time, so you _should_ be good to go.

Comment: Each database product may have different syntax for this.  Have you checked the database help on the web? What did it say, and why didn't it work when you tried it on your data?  It seems like you need to be asking the database for just the date from the datetime field, but you haven't given enough info.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
...
WHERE med_date > '2021-06-08'
```

will get you all values that are after midnight at the start of today.

If you want to compute daily statistics then use `CAST(... AS date)` such as

```
SELECT CAST(med_date AS date) AS med_date, COUNT(*) AS n
FROM TheTable
GROUP BY CAST(med_date AS date)
ORDER BY 1
```

Answer (score 0):

If you're using entity framework and LINQ to SQL queries, you can filter for date this way. Is that what you looking for?

```
dbcontext.DbSet<YouerEntity>.Where(x=>x.med_data.Date >= Date)
```